# AngularJS with Google charts data loading from server

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization

I am trying to use Google Charts together with Angular JS. The code is as given below. When I run this sample with data populated locally within the controller the chart renders correctly. However when I try to load the data from a remote server using Restangular then I get an error 
Cannot read property '0' of null×

The code is available in plnkr as well - http://plnkr.co/edit/xoF32oVDOFlXABGqf2R8?p=preview.

Any suggestions as to what could be going wrong ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/restangular/1.3.1/restangular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.6.0/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .bigGraph {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            float: left;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var googleChart = googleChart || angular.module("google-chart", []);

        googleChart.directive("googleChart", function() {
            return {
                restrict: "A",
                link: function($scope, $elem, $attr) {
                    var dt = $scope[$attr.ngModel].dataTable;

                    var options = {};
                    if ($scope[$attr.ngModel].title)
                        options.title = $scope[$attr.ngModel].title;

                    var googleChart = new google.visualization[$attr.googleChart]($elem[0]);
                    googleChart.draw(dt, options)
                }
            }
        });

        google.setOnLoadCallback(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['my-app']);
        });
        google.load('visualization', '1', {
            packages: ['corechart']
        });


        var myApp = myApp || angular.module("my-app", ['restangular', 'google-chart']);

        myApp.factory('testService', function($http, Restangular) {

            var exports = {};

            exports.getRestangular = function() {
                return Restangular.setBaseUrl("https://cdn.rawgit.com/venkyvb/164b6c12a4f8bc72a02b12234a32bc9c/raw/427112f2ff71eb62aee794ce85c6cc869d33eb62");
            }

            exports.getSummary = function() {
                return exports.getRestangular().all("summary.json").getList();
            }

            return exports;
        });

        myApp.controller("IndexCtrl", function($scope, testService) {
            $scope.data1 = {};

            $scope.data1.dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("string", "Step");
            $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("number", "Server Time");
            $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("number", "No of Transactions");
            $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("number", "");
            $scope.data1.dataTable.addColumn("number", "E2E Time");

            $scope.summary = [];
            testService.getSummary().then(function(data) {
                    $scope.summary = data;

                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var aRow = [];
                        aRow.push(data[i].step);
                        aRow.push(parseFloat(data[i].serv_time));
                        aRow.push(parseFloat(data[i].total_transactions));
                        aRow.push(parseFloat(data[i].e2e_time));
                        aRow.push(parseFloat(data[i].e2e_time));
                        $scope.data1.dataTable.addRow(aRow);
                    };

                    $scope.data1.title = "Server response times"

                },
                function(data) {
                    // Error
                });

        });
    </script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="IndexCtrl">
    <div google-chart="BubbleChart" ng-model="data1" class="bigGraph"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: have you checked the error callback for exceptions?

Comment: Yes, there are no exceptions. Also in the Chrome console there are no errors.